# How do I correctly load a webform using Ajax?

Tags: views, 8, ajax, webforms

The page I need to make is a bit complex and my team and I face many problems with it.

We need to have a page with multiples sections (just square blocs with text on it). Each section displays (on click) a select. When we click on that select, we have to load a webform using AJAX and here is our problem.

We created a view with a select exposed filter and when we change the select value, a webform is loaded in AJAX. BUT only the HTML is here, the input masks on the fields are not loaded until we click again on the apply button for loading another webform (or the same as the first one, doesn't matter).

So, how can we correctly load our webform?

And, even if the masks are loaded on the second load, we don't have our custom handler called when we submit the form. Instead, we are redirect to htp://ourwebsite.com/views/ajax and the custom handler is never called.

Edit : Here are some screen shots.

[image: first one]
[image: second one]
[image: third one]

In the first, this is a content type which contains the view with a select (the one that will load the webform using ajax).
In the second one, we see the webform loaded after the FIRST click on "Apply" : the input masks are not loaded.
In the third one, I just clicked once again the Apply button and when the webform is load, we see the input masks. But even in this case, the custom handler is not called when the webform is submit

Comment: Can you load then webform regularly without Ajax? Also, can u elaborate on the masks? And post relevant code | screen shots? I’m also, not clear on the desired outcome. Maybe describe that clearly a bit

Comment: First:  yes, without ajax, the webform is working absolutely fine. the masks, the custom handler, all of that works
I will post screen shots :)